# CSS background URL not displaying inside Bootstrap container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a `.container` from Twitter Bootstrap which I am currently setting a row to have a background url() of an image, which I would like to span the entire viewport width. 
Currently, however, the image is not displaying at all, even though I know I have the accurate path to the asset as when I look at `View Source` and open the `src` url in a new tab it shows the image.

Here is my haml file:

```
.container
  .row
    .my_div
      This is the div that does't display the bckgd url
  %p
  %p
  %br/
  .row
    .col-md-4
      .quote
        I will never forget the time I spent here.
        .signature Jeremy, Switzerland
    .col-md-4
      .quote
        Since I entered FLS, I have never regretted my decision because the classes offered by FLS are all fantastic.
        .signature Chia-Yuan, Taiwan
    .col-md-4
      .quote
        The quality of teachers is good.
        .signature Masaru, Japan

%br
%br
#instafeed
.container
  %br/
  .row
    .col-md-4
    %div{class: "col-md-4\""}
      %video{controls: "", height: "240", width: "320"}
        %source{src: "movie.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
          %source{src: "movie.ogg", type: "video/ogg"}
           Your browser does not support the video tag.
    .col-md-4
      .quote
        Boston is [a] really attractive city for me.
        .signature Takashi, Japan
  / row
  %br/
  .row
    .col-md-4
   .col-md-4
      .quote
        I have had many good experiences at FLS.
        .signature Fukiko, Japan
    .col-md-4
      .quote
        The teachers are qualified and friendly.
        .signature Tatyana, Russia
        / style
      / quote
    / column
  / row
  %br/
/ container
```

Here is the CSS

```
html .my_div{
  background: url(image_path("photo_With_valid_path.jpg"));
  background-origin:initial;
  background-repeat-x:initial;
  background-repeat-y:initial;
  background-clip:initial;
  background-position:center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}
```

Even after editing all of the CSS i didn't understand, and removing the Rails framework, It seems that the following is not a valid way to display a background image:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lc0dptgs/

So I am clearly missing some basic component here.

I have attached a screenshot of what is rendered in Chrome, and the CSS that is associated with the div as well as what is displayed: which is a div of 0px height hence no bckgd photo.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background css has two parenthesis at the end.

```
background: url(image_path("photo_With_valid_path.jpg"));
```

Remove the one and things should work.

```
background: url(image_path("photo_With_valid_path.jpg") !important;
```

**Example:** [jsFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc0dptgs/2/)

Comment: Thank you! you are totally right. Unfortunately, when I plug in the now-functioning-CSS from the fiddle verbatim into my rails css for `.my_div` I still get zilch for a background img.

Comment: The problem might be the css order precedence. Just because css cascades it still follows some hierarchy.  I would try putting: !improtant in that background call. I have updated the answer to reflect that. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: what do you mean? remove the !important?

Comment: Add the !important (look at the example, I have added it there). This will overrule any hierarchy in the CSS.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately that is not working for me. This is the compiled CSS as viewed in the browser: `.my_div {
  background: url("/assets/photo_With_valid_path.jpg") !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover !important;
}`